# How to use append in lists?

Tags: python, python-3.6

What's wrong in this code. I tried but failed to append the items or anything.

```
suitcase = [] 
suitcase.append(sunglasses)


suitcase.append(sungses)
suitcase.append(sungsses)
suitcase.append(sungl)

list_length = len(suitcase)

print ("There are %d items in the suitcase." % (list_length))
print (suitcase)
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so, you should read them.

Comment: Are those supposed to be strings?  Also you tagged the question Python 3.6, but `print suitcase` is Python 2 syntax

Comment: oh sry but still its not happening...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It seems to me that you lack some context like what you are trying to do and how the objects are defined which you try to append. Please include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal,complete code example. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 5th got it will implement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to append string as number.

```
    suitcase = []

    # an element is added
    suitcase.append('sunglasses')

    suitcase.append('sungses')
    suitcase.append('sungsses')
    suitcase.append('sungl')


    list_length = len(suitcase)

    print ("There are %d items in the suitcase." % (list_length))
    print (suitcase)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
suitcase = [] 
suitcase.append("sunglasses")


suitcase.append("sungses")
suitcase.append("sungsses")
suitcase.append("sungl")

list_length = len(suitcase)

print("There are %d items in the suitcase." % (list_length))
print(suitcase)
```

If you're in python 3.0+ your print statements are wrong.  Furthermore, if you're trying to add strings to the list, you need to put quotations or literals around them.  Unless they're variables, ie. `sunglasses = 5` then doing `suitcase.append(sunglasses)` would append `5` to the end of the list.